# How to print the number of repetitions of a word

Tags: java, numbers, cpu-word

What I am trying to do is write a word and search in which file that word is found and the number of times it contains it

Example:

The word dog is found in:

```
file1.html - 2
file6.hmtl - 8
file25.html - 5
```

Currently I have this, which only shows me the name of the file but not the number of repetitions.

Any help is welcome.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File dir = new File("/Users/Adan/Desktop/Files/"); // directory = target directory.

        if(dir.exists()){ // Directory exists then proceed.

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("casa"); // keyword = keyword to search in files.
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of files.

            System.out.println("La palabra " + p + " esta dentro de estos archivos:");


            for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
                if(!f.isFile()){

                    continue;
                }
                try
                {

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                    fis.read(data);
                    String text = new String(data);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                    if(m.find()){
                        list.add(f.getName()); // add file to found-keyword list.

                    }

                    fis.close();
                } 
                catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println("\n\t Error processing file : "+f.getName());
                }

            }
            for (String listado : list) { 
                System.out.println(listado);//Lista
            }
        } // IF directory exists then only process.
        else{
            System.out.println("\n Directory doesn't exist.");
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File dir = new File("D:/test2"); // directory = target directory.

    if (dir.exists()) { // Directory exists then proceed.

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("sd4"); // keyword = keyword to search in files.
        Map<String, Long> occurences = new HashMap<>(); // list of files.

        System.out.println("La palabra " + p + " esta dentro de estos archivos:");


        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (!f.isFile()) {

                continue;
            }
            try {

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                fis.read(data);
                String text = new String(data);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                while (m.find()) { //use while instead of if
                    occurences.put(f.getName(), occurences.getOrDefault(f.getName(), 0L) + 1); // add file to found-keyword list.
                }

                fis.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("\n\t Error processing file : " + f.getName());
            }

        }
        occurences.forEach((file, numberOfOccurrences) -> {
            System.out.println("In the file [" + file + "] the word occurs : " + numberOfOccurrences + " times");
        });
    } // IF directory exists then only process.
    else {
        System.out.println("\n Directory doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```